# Trying to add a select element to a table dynamically but its not showing up in the cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, html-table

I've already managed to successfully insert various elements dynamically into separate cells of a table per row such as label, checkbox and input text type. However, when I try to insert a select element with the options it doesn't show up in the row and also, all the other elements stop appearing as well.

As you can see, I'm using Javascript HTML DOM to add (append) the elements to the parents - all elements appear in the respective cells per row up until I try to append the select element, then nothing shows in the table, no elememnts, no rows, cells, nothing.

Can anyone enlighten me here - is it a style problem?

Thanks.

Here is my CSS, HTML and SCRIPT codes as follows. Questions is a 2 dim array to populate the elements appended to the cells

```js
function fillTable(questions) {

  var questsLength = questions.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < questsLength; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.setAttribute = ("id", i);
    var col1 = document.createElement("td");
    var col2 = document.createElement("td");
    var col3 = document.createElement("td");
    var col4 = document.createElement("td");

    var qno = document.createElement("label");
    qno.innerHTML = i + 1;
    col1.appendChild(qno);
    row.appendChild(col1);
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    col2.appendChild(checkbox);
    row.appendChild(col2);
    var question = document.createElement("input");
    question.type = "text";
    question.value = questions[i][1];
    col3.appendChild(question);
    row.appendChild(col3);

    var questOpts = document.createElement("select");
    var alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
    for (var j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = alphabet[j];
      option.innerHTML = alphabet[j];
      questOpts.appendChild(option);
    }

    col4.appendChild(questOpts);
    row.appendChild(col4);

    var tab = document.getElementById("bdy");
    tab.appendChild(row);
  }
}
```

```css
.fixTableHead {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

.fixTableHead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border: 2px solid #529432;
  background: #ffffff;
}

th {
  background: #ABDD93;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixTableHead">
  <table id="bdy">
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>Answer options</th>
      <th>Question type</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo: `creatElement` should be `createElement`. Didn't you see the error message in the console?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/6063

Comment: Thanks, i will try that.